# Poco library for c++, declare namespace for custom element

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I want to create an XML document by building a DOM document from scratch, with syntax like:

```
AutoPtr<Document> doc = new Document;
AutoPtr<Element> root = doc->createElement("root");
doc->appendChild(root);
AutoPtr<Element> element1 = doc->createElementNS("http://ns1", "ns1:element1");
root->appendChild(element1);
AutoPtr<Element> element2 = doc->createElementNS("http://ns1", "ns1:element2");
root->appendChild(element2);

DOMWriter writer;
writer.setNewLine("\n");
writer.setOptions(XMLWriter::PRETTY_PRINT);
writer.writeNode(std::cout, doc);
```

But, when I write it, I get next result:

```
<root>
   <ns1:element1 xmlns:ns1="http://ns1"/>
   <ns1:element2 xmlns:ns1="http://ns1"/>
</root>
```

So namespace ns1 declared two times, and I want to declare it inside "root" element.
Is there way to get next representation:

```
<root xmlns:ns1="http://ns1"/>
   <ns1:element1/>
   <ns1:element2/>
</root>
```

Comment: `root->setAttribute("xmlns:ns1", "http://ns1");` or mb `root->setAttributeNS("", "xmlns:ns1", "http://ns1");` ?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, in spite of we get <root xmlns:ns1="h_ttp://ns1">

Comment: The only solution I've found for now- add a dummy attribute declared in this namespace, and after generating string representation remove it... but it is too tricky